# Bad scope in forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, button, event-handling, scope

I'm working on a forms application and seem to be misinterpreting something about the scope of my methods. I have 2 working methods Split and AddToDatabase, and I am trying to call them from the button1_click event handler. Within the handler, however, Split() and AddToDatabase() are highlighted red saying that they don't exist in the current context... Does anybody know why this might be? Thanks

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Content
    {
        public void Split()
        {
           //
        }

        public void AddToDatabase()
        {
           // 
        }
    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                string root = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Split();
            AddtoDataBase();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst the answers people have posted are correct you need to be aware that member access within the class `Content` will be outside the scope of the `Form1` class. My gut says that your intention in `Content.x/y` is to reference members of `Form1`. You could  consider making these methods part of `Form1` if that is the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because they are in a different class. You'd need this:

```
var c = new Content();
c.Split();
c.AddToDatabase();
```

but this begs the question whether or not they need to be instance methods. If they don't store any state, make them `static`:

```
public static void Split() ...

public static void AddToDatabase() ...
```

and then call them like this:

```
Content.Split();
Content.AddToDatabase();
```

Answer (score 2):

They don't exist in that scope, because you have put them inside another class (`Content`).  Without knowing *why* you did that I'm guessing at the "right answer, but you either need to create an instance of `Content` and call `Split` and `AddToDatabase` on *that* or move the methods to your main form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access by using `instance` of `Content` class as those methods are declared in different class `Content`

**Example:**

```
    Content c=new Content();
    c.Split();
    c.AddtoDataBase();
```

Answer (score 1):

They are defined in the `Content` class not the `Form1` class

Try the following.

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var content = new Content();
        content.Split();
        content.AddtoDataBase();
    }
```

Also you currently have defined your `Content` class without defining if it is `public`, `private` etc, so it will default to `internal`.

Finally as you build up more and more of your code, you will find that having multiple classes inside the same file will make it really hard to find your methods. Try separating them into different files, usually `Content.cs` and `Form1.cs`